# How to eliminate white space on a page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bbpress

I need help to figuring out how can erase the withe space on the rigth of my [forum](http://valledelerma.esy.es/forums/) page(reference:https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIh2g.png)

Im a noob with web design so I cant find my way around easily, so far I find the line that gives shape to the section I want to change.I know this because I found that changing the highligth line `class="main col-lg-9 col-md-8"` to `class="main col-lg-9 col-md-12"` does the trick just using the developer tool available in Maxthon browser.
I understand I have to put a CSS rule in my wordpress site but I cant find the rigth way to do it.

Maybe there is some other way to do it? I will be very grateful if someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using bootstrap. This will solve your problem:

```
class="main col-lg-12 col-md-12"
```

Adjusting the numbers in the "col-lg" or "col-md" affects how wide things will get. A number of 12 means fill up the whole screen.

So "col-lg-12" means be as wide as the whole screen. "col-lg-6" means be half the width of the whole screen. And so on.

Also, "md" means be this wide on medium sized screens (think laptop to tablet). "lg" means be this wide on a big screen (a desktop or large laptop).

Comment: Yeah, as @resolute_coder has said, it's the bootstrap classes that do it — you don't need more CSS, just change the classes in your theme and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but I'd say you want the forum to be full width on all devices? If that's the case you can remove `col-lg-9` and `col-md-12`.

Those to classes mean the following:

`col-lg-9` - on large screens make this element 9 cols wide (out of 12)
`col-md-12` - on medium screens make this element 12 cols wide (out of 12)

I'd recommend you read this:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! I finally got something from the dev console, reading the info you guys provided make me learn something so I found the class "Main" in the files of my Wordpress theme and then just comment it.